# AwesomeFont is not changing font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

Im just starting creating Websites.
I want to you font-awesome for my Symbol and as Text font.
Unfortunately even though I imported everything some parts don't work.
I got all the Icons working and even the animated stuff is just fine.

I also installed the font to my PC but I don't get my Browser to change the actual font.
When I type

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
```

It simply does nothing but uses Times New Roman.

Is there anything i missed?
Here is my actual .css and .html with the relevant parts:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>foo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0\css\font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
</head>
```

and

```
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto 300px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2;      
}
```

Comment: you have the wrong slashes for the href.

Comment: You shouldn't use the fontawesome in the body as `font-family`. Did you read the "how to" in the website?

Comment: Have you included the necessary Font Awesome font-declarations in your CSS-file?

Comment: font awesome uses certain chars that aren't english words

Comment: I red the Get-Started part which says nothing about font family so i did this implicit. Is there another Documentation called "how to" than http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ ?

Comment: *"....and as Text font"* -- Font Awesome does **not** contain alphanumeric text characters. You can't use it for text, it's only for symbols/icons. AND you have to either link to a repository for the actual font files, or download them and install them on your server.

Comment: thanks for the slashes hint, but it didnt fix it. What do i need to include in my CSS file?

Comment: Thanks Scott... maybe i got on the wrong trace by font. I think your Answer is correct and i missunderstood what font awesome actually was/is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"....and as Text font"*

FontAwesome does **not** contain alphanumeric text characters. You can't use it for text, it's only for symbols/icons.

In addition, you have to either link to a cnd repository for the actual font files (.otf, .eot, .svg, .woff, .woff2), or download them and install them on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i made a misstake in thinking that font awesome is something i can get another text style. It's only for Icons as @Scott said in one of the Comments.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the font-awesome you should include the relevant `css` file and use the elements with the relevant classes.

Here is an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
```

The relevant part is `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` - the "code" for the camera icon is actually the class `fa-camera-retro` inside the `<i>` element.

For the complete list of icons (and the names of the classes to use) you can visit the complete [icon list](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).